# black spots on the object in edit and object mode

Tags: texturing

The object I downloaded from internet is covered in black spots. There is no texture or material on it. How can I delete them?[image]

Comment: FYI, could be hard to solve it (inverted normals or non manifold faces) in this kind of mesh (it depends).

Comment: Not necessarily flipped normals, I think it's due to bad topology, e.g. triangles, bent quads, n-gons... If you want us take a look at your file, you could upload it to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then edit your question (edit link below it) and add the link you get from there.